# Add delimeters to CMD Prompt output file

Tags: cmd, output, echo, delimiter

I utilizing command line to output folder/files to a text file:

```
C:\>FORFILES /S /C "CMD /C ECHO @relpath @fsize @fdate @ftime" > C:/temp/list.txt
```

What I would like to do is to add a delimiter between, something like |, between the File Path, Size and Date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want delimiters, then just put them in there ;-). But yes, some, such as `|` will need to be escaped with `^`, as in:

```
FORFILES /S /C "CMD /C ECHO @relpath^|@fsize^|@fdate @ftime" > C:/temp/list.txt
```

Comment: ahhh.. was missing the great escape.